# Reordering UITableView sections on the iPhone by dragging (like reordering rows)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there anything currently in the SDK that allows for re-ordering of tableView sections? As in, move the entire section below or above an adjacent section? This is plausible with individual UITableViewCells. Haven't seen it done for sections though.

Comment: hi i also want to perform same operation did u get any success???

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not ideal but fairly simple so worth considering:
Add Up/Down buttons to your section headers. Down on the first, Up on the last and Up and Down on all the others. Then respond to the button presses by programmatically re-ordering the table. Up moves the section up one and Down moves the section down one.
Martin

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in touch-responsive API for moving table view sections - you'd have to do it programmatically then send a `[tableView reloadData]` message or similar.

It is concievable, though, that you create a table view where each UITableViewCell's view is itself a UITableView containing a section of your data, so that the cells in the "master" table are draggable as UITableViewCells. This would let you reorder "sections" in your table, but they wouldn't be sections anymore - they'd be separate tables, each with a single section.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe as an alternative idea, reloadData on the table to only show the sections as a kind of "collapsed all" view on your table (maybe it is possible to even animate this?) which then has one section, containing all sections as row elements.  The only extra required would then be a  button that will set your table to this state.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to move rows from one section to another, while updating the datasource of course. But this seemed to be mission impossible. Empty cells in between, wrong contents in sections, wrong ordering of sections were the only results I got.

Comment: (Better late than never) The trick is to add footers to sections(maybe just the empty ones) this creates a void for you to move the rows in. See here: http://davemeehan.com/technology/moving-uitableviewcell-between-sections-in-grouped-uitableview